# Separate signup processes for child classes of User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to set up 2 slightly different signup processes for my User child classes - Member and Partner.  I want to make it so:

/users/sign_up signs up a User as a Member (so I have a hidden field in there with the value 'Member') and it works like a charm.

But also I want:

/users/partner/sign_up to provide a slightly different form that ascribes them the value 'Partner'.

I specifically want this achieved with 2 separate URLs, so I can send these different types of user a different link to sign up with.

I'm using Devise for my authentication system.

I'm pretty sure I should generate a separate controller, something like partner_registrations_controller and have it inherit from devise, but I have no idea what code should then go in the controller.

I also think I need to create a new folder 'partner_registrations' within the views/users folder, where I would have the specific 'new.html.erb' form.

And I finally I know I need to do something with the routes, like:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations } do
      get 'users/partner/sign_up', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
  end
```

I've read this wiki page on github: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-routes-to-user-registration-pages](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-routes-to-user-registration-pages) but I'm non the wiser for it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, so thought I'd post the answer in case anyone else finds it useful in the future:

Routes file:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_up', to: 'members#new', controller: {registrations: "members"}
    get 'partners/sign_up', to: 'content_partners#new', controller: {registrations: "content_partners"}
  end
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: :registrations}
```

I created 2 separate controllers for each child class, with basically the same new and create actions as given by devise:

```
class MembersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    respond_with resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
end
```

I just replaced 'Members' for 'ContentPartners' in the controller for the other child class.

I then created 2 new folders in the Views/Users folder - watch out for the gotcha that got me, they have to be pluralized too - so /members and /content_partners.  Then in each folder I created a unique 'new.html.erb' file.

That's it.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but I think this could the answer to my problem. Is it possible to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350591/rails-5-new-user-in-different-controller-with-devise and help me get my head straight? I am trying to build multiple sign_up forms for all of the conditions in my app. There are 4 types of sign_ups, and 3 of them come from an existing user. Only the first one is external with the devise registration form/controller. Thank you for reading this.